# check if an app work on jailbreak device

Tags: iphone

I have one free app and hope to inform the users to upgrade app when there is new version.
But I need to detect if the app works on a jailbreak device.
Is there a way to check  if an app work on jailbreak device?
I try to read the info of Info.plist, but failed.

Welcome any comment

Comment: Did you mean you want to determine whether the device is jailbroken or not?

Comment: get a jailbroken device and try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code to the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. This will identify the jail broken devices and do whatever you want.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];

if ([info objectForKey: @"SignerIdentity"] != nil) {
        NSLog(@"jail broken");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreaking allows iOS users to gain root access to the operating system ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking)). 
It means that your App has access to file system with root privileges on jailbroken device. 
Just try to access to any file outside of sandbox (create, modify, etc). If it's possible the device is jailbroken.

Comment: "Just try to access to any file outside of sandbox (create, modify, etc). If it's possible the device is jailbroken." - actually, it's not true, and I know that's for sure, my app plays system ringtones like marimba and harp. By the way, app may be rejected even if it tries to access files outside of sandbox.